# Помощь в оптимизации JS кода

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Как можно оптимизировать и уменьшить этот код? По факту это одни и те же значения, только выполняются для 25 ячеек. Как видите в коде это занимает уйму места и влияет на время загрузки и подсчета.
Не обязательно все, но возможно часть можно сделать проще.

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var answers = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="1"]').length;

var answer1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="1"][value="1"]').length;
var answer2 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="2"][value="1"]').length;
var answer3 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="3"][value="1"]').length;
var answer4 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="4"][value="1"]').length;
var answer5 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="5"][value="1"]').length;
var answer6 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="6"][value="1"]').length;
var answer7 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="7"][value="1"]').length;
var answer8 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="8"][value="1"]').length;
var answer9 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="9"][value="1"]').length;
var answer10 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="10"][value="1"]').length;
var answer11 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="11"][value="1"]').length;
var answer12 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="12"][value="1"]').length;
var answer13 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="13"][value="1"]').length;
var answer14 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="14"][value="1"]').length;
var answer15 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="15"][value="1"]').length;
var answer16 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="16"][value="1"]').length;
var answer17 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="17"][value="1"]').length;
var answer18 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="18"][value="1"]').length;
var answer19 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="19"][value="1"]').length;
var answer20 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="20"][value="1"]').length;
var answer21 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="21"][value="1"]').length;
var answer22 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="22"][value="1"]').length;
var answer23 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="23"][value="1"]').length;
var answer24 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="24"][value="1"]').length
var answer25 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="25"][value="1"]').length;;


for (var i = 0, j = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, res1 = 0, res2 = 0, res3 = 0, res4 = 0, res5 = 0, res6 = 0, res7 = 0, res8 = 0, res9 = 0, res10 = 0, res11 = 0, res12 = 0, res13 = 0, res14 = 0, res15 = 0, res16 = 0, res17 = 0, res18 = 0, res19 = 0, res20 = 0, res21 = 0, res22 = 0, res23 = 0, res24 = 0, res25 = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function(e) {
    var el = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    if (el.checked) {
      el.setAttribute('checked', "1");
      if (el.name === '1' && el.value === '1') {
        res1 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '2' && el.value === '1') {
        res2 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '3' && el.value === '1') {
        res3 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '4' && el.value === '1') {
        res4 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '5' && el.value === '1') {
        res5 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '6' && el.value === '1') {
        res6 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '7' && el.value === '1') {
        res7 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '8' && el.value === '1') {
        res8 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '9' && el.value === '1') {
        res9 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '10' && el.value === '1') {
        res10 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '11' && el.value === '1') {
        res11 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '12' && el.value === '1') {
        res12 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '13' && el.value === '1') {
        res13 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '14' && el.value === '1') {
        res14 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '15' && el.value === '1') {
        res15 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '16' && el.value === '1') {
        res16 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '17' && el.value === '1') {
        res17 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '18' && el.value === '1') {
        res18 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '19' && el.value === '1') {
        res19 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '20' && el.value === '1') {
        res20 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '21' && el.value === '1') {
        res21 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '22' && el.value === '1') {
        res22 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '23' && el.value === '1') {
        res23 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '24' && el.value === '1') {
        res24 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '25' && el.value === '1') {
        res25 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      j++;
    } else {
      el.setAttribute('checked', "0");
      if (el.name === '1' && el.value === '1') {
        res1 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '2' && el.value === '1') {
        res2 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '3' && el.value === '1') {
        res3 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '4' && el.value === '1') {
        res4 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '5' && el.value === '1') {
        res5 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '6' && el.value === '1') {
        res6 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '7' && el.value === '1') {
        res7 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '8' && el.value === '1') {
        res8 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '9' && el.value === '1') {
        res9 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '10' && el.value === '1') {
        res10 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '11' && el.value === '1') {
        res11 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '12' && el.value === '1') {
        res12 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '13' && el.value === '1') {
        res13 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '14' && el.value === '1') {
        res14 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '15' && el.value === '1') {
        res15 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '16' && el.value === '1') {
        res16 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '17' && el.value === '1') {
        res17 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '18' && el.value === '1') {
        res18 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '19' && el.value === '1') {
        res19 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '20' && el.value === '1') {
        res20 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '21' && el.value === '1') {
        res21 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '22' && el.value === '1') {
        res22 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '23' && el.value === '1') {
        res23 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '24' && el.value === '1') {
        res24 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '25' && el.value === '1') {
        res25 -= parseInt(el.value);
      }
      j--;
    }
    document.getElementById('p1').innerText = '1: ' + res1 + ' /2: ' + res2 + ' /3: ' + res3 + ' /4: ' + res4 + ' /5: ' + res5 + ' /6: ' + res6 + ' /7: ' + res7 + ' /8: ' + res8 + ' /9: ' + res9 + ' /10: ' + res10 + ' /11: ' + res11 + ' /12: ' + res12 + ' /13: ' + res13 + ' /14: ' + res14 + ' /15: ' + res15 + ' /16: ' + res16 + ' /17: ' + res17 + ' /18: ' + res18 + ' /19: ' + res19 + ' /20: ' + res20 + ' /21: ' + res21 + ' /22: ' + res22 + ' /23: ' + res23 + ' /24: ' + res24 + ' /25: ' + res25;
  }
}

var bad = '';
var good = '';
document.getElementById('result').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
  if (j === 0)
    document.getElementById('div1').innerText = "Ничего не выбрано";
  else if (j >= answers || j < answers) {
    if (res1 < answer1 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="1"][checked="1"]').length > answer1) {
      bad += "№ 1; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 1; ";
    }
    if (res2 < answer2 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="2"][checked="1"]').length > answer2) {
      bad += "№ 2; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 2; ";
    }
    if (res3 < answer3 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="3"][checked="1"]').length > answer3) {
      bad += "№ 3; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 3; ";
    }
    if (res4 < answer4 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="4"][checked="1"]').length > answer4) {
      bad += "№ 4; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 4; ";
    }
    if (res5 < answer5 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="5"][checked="1"]').length > answer5) {
      bad += "№ 5; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 5; ";
    }
    if (res6 < answer6 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="6"][checked="1"]').length > answer6) {
      bad += "№ 6; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 6; ";
    }
    if (res7 < answer7 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="7"][checked="1"]').length > answer7) {
      bad += "№ 7; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 7; ";
    }
    if (res8 < answer8 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="8"][checked="1"]').length > answer8) {
      bad += "№ 8; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 8; ";
    }
    if (res9 < answer9 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="9"][checked="1"]').length > answer9) {
      bad += "№ 9; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 9; ";
    }
    if (res10 < answer10 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="10"][checked="1"]').length > answer10) {
      bad += "№ 10; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 10; ";
    }
    if (res11 < answer11 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="11"][checked="1"]').length > answer11) {
      bad += "№ 11; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 11; ";
    }
    if (res12 < answer12 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="12"][checked="1"]').length > answer12) {
      bad += "№ 12; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 12; ";
    }
    if (res13 < answer13 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="13"][checked="1"]').length > answer13) {
      bad += "№ 13; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 13; ";
    }
    if (res14 < answer14 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="14"][checked="1"]').length > answer14) {
      bad += "№ 14; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 14; ";
    }
    if (res15 < answer15 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="15"][checked="1"]').length > answer15) {
      bad += "№ 15; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 15; ";
    }
    if (res16 < answer16 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="16"][checked="1"]').length > answer16) {
      bad += "№ 16; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 16; ";
    }
    if (res17 < answer17 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="17"][checked="1"]').length > answer17) {
      bad += "№ 17; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 17; ";
    }
    if (res18 < answer18 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="18"][checked="1"]').length > answer18) {
      bad += "№ 18; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 18; ";
    }
    if (res19 < answer19 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="19"][checked="1"]').length > answer19) {
      bad += "№ 19; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 19; ";
    }
    if (res20 < answer20 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="20"][checked="1"]').length > answer20) {
      bad += "№ 20; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 20; ";
    }
    if (res21 < answer21 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="21"][checked="1"]').length > answer21) {
      bad += "№ 21; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 21; ";
    }
    if (res22 < answer22 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="22"][checked="1"]').length > answer22) {
      bad += "№ 22; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 22; ";
    }
    if (res23 < answer23 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="23"][checked="1"]').length > answer23) {
      bad += "№ 23; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 23; ";
    }
    if (res24 < answer24 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="24"][checked="1"]').length > answer24) {
      bad += "№ 24; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 24; ";
    }
    if (res25 < answer25 || document.querySelectorAll('input[name="25"][checked="1"]').length > answer25) {
      bad += "№ 25; ";
    } else {
      good += "№ 25; ";
    }
    document.getElementById('div1').innerText = "Верно: " + good + "\n Неверно: " + bad;
    bad = '';
    good = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Глянуть не лень. Переписывать и вникать лень. Для начала могу посоветовать самостоятельно изучить, как работают [циклы](http://javascript.ru/for) и [массивы](http://javascript.ru/array) в Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var answer1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="1"][value="1"]').length;`
Заменяется на

```
var answers = new Array();
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
  answers.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + i + '"][value="1"]').length);
```

```
for (var i = 0, j = 0, a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, res1 = 0, res2 = 0, res3 = 0, res4 = 0, res5 = 0, res6 = 0, res7 = 0, res8 = 0, res9 = 0, res10 = 0, res11 = 0, res12 = 0, res13 = 0, res14 = 0, res15 = 0, res16 = 0, res17 = 0, res18 = 0, res19 = 0, res20 = 0, res21 = 0, res22 = 0, res23 = 0, res24 = 0, res25 = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function(e) {
    var el = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    if (el.checked) {
      el.setAttribute('checked', "1");
      if (el.name === '1' && el.value === '1') {
        res1 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
      if (el.name === '2' && el.value === '1') {
        res2 += parseInt(el.value);
      }
```

Заменяется на

```
res = new Array(25);
res.fill(0);
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function(e) {
    var el = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
    var val = (el.checked) ? 1 : 0;
    el.setAttribute('checked', val);
    if (!val) val--;
    if (el.value === '1')
      res[parseInt(el.name) - 1] += val;
}
```

Дальше не смотрел